# How do I create a tooltip in CSS that works for both long and short content?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to follow the W3Schools guide on creating tooltips with CSS, but I'm having some trouble getting it to work well with variable-length tooltip text. Specifically, I want the with of the tooltip to automatically adjust to the content.

Here's a JSFiddle with the verbatim example from the W3Schools guide: https://jsfiddle.net/3eujkrb0/4/

I've tried to modify that to make both long and short tooltip texts to look good, but I can't manage the tooltip to become wide enough too look good with a longer text, without specifying a `width` or `min-width` so wide that it looks awful with short texts.

Here's a JSFiddle with my attempts: https://jsfiddle.net/3eujkrb0/5/

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 105%;
  transform: translate(10px, -50%);
  width: 350px;
  /* uncomment this to see behavior without hard-coded widht */
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.container {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="tooltip">Shorter text
    <span class="tooltiptext">A short tooltip.</span>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="container">

  <div class="tooltip">Longer text
    <span class="tooltiptext">When I try to make it work with longer text in the tooltip, I can't make it look good. Either I have to specify a fixed width or min-width for the tooltip, which makes it look decent for longer texts but awful for short ones, or I don't, and the longer text only expands vertically, assuming the lowest possible width without overflow.
  <br />
  <br />
  Also, the positioning doesn't work well with tooltips spanning multiple lines.</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: If you don't mind the tooltip being constricted to one line, simply removing the `width: ...` altogether and adding `white-space:nowrap;` will do the trick.

Comment: @MrLister That's unfortunately not good enough; the tooltip text will sometimes be so long that it won't fit on the screen on one line.

Comment: what's the class for the short tooltip?

Comment: @RachelGallen An artifact of me trying to fit both examples in a single fiddle. Sorry :)

Comment: @TomasLycken I made a mistake when posting my answer initially. I have corrected it! Please review it again.. thanks.  .. I actually didn't see the w3c example until right this second! grr,..the pointer of the tooltip isn't completely center-aligned with the text label